# Can you assign a value to a returned object?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am trying to implement Euclid's algorithm in Python3.
If max(a, b) returns the object with the largest value in (a, b), 
why can't you operate on that object like so:

`max(a, b) %= min(a, b)`

Comment: Assignment isn't an operation on objects in Python. `x = y` has no effect on the object previously bound to the `x` variable; it's purely an operation on the variable itself.

Comment: You can't, no. Names are not objects, and can't be returned from a function. `max()` returns *values*, objects that names reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
>>> max(a, b) %= min(a, b)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

The interpreter has spoken. You are trying to operate on a value/object, which is not possible. Assignments can be performed on variables only, which are references pointing to said values/objects.

Even if you could do it, it's pointless, because you're trying to change the return value of a function, that hasn't been captured by any variable. You can't even use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the short answer to your question is **no**. The function max(a,b) is returning the largest value to you, not a variable reference to the largest value.

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
if max(a,b) == a:
    a %= min(a,b)
else
    b %= min(a,b)
```

which will check if the largest value is indeed the variable a before the assignment.

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice if the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) stated value and not item. Aren't items in iterables stored as references to variables?

Comment: @Lupilum No, items in iterables are values.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign to variables, but there's no way for a function to return a variable. (It can only return a value.)

For example:

```
a = 4
b = 5
max(a, b)  # What does this return?
```

`max(a, b)` returns the *value* `5`, not the *variable* `b`. (So the code you're trying to write is essentially `5 = ...` which makes little sense.)

Comment: Sorry but -1, since this is not the reason it's not allowed. The error you get from running the OP's code is `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` and not `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`(as you said, `5=...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like this, the function `max` returns a value, not a variable, what you can do, however is to execute:

```
a,b = sorted((a,b))
```

then, after this line, `a` will always be the greater value (or equal `b`)

this way you can just do in the line after:

```
a%=b
```

Since b will be the min value...

Comment: Or just a, b = sorted(a, b)

Comment: `sorted` doesn't work that way. `sorted([a, b])` would work, but this is way off-topic already.

Comment: Or, rather, sorted((a, b)) since sorted needs an iterable.

Comment: @Lupilum That would work too. Whether you pass a tuple or a list doesn't really matter. (Perhaps one is slightly faster?)

Comment: I timed it, tuple seems to be a bit faster (around 0.85 s) vs. list (around 0.90 s) for        timeit.timeit('a=5;b=6;c=sorted((a,b))', number=1000000) and the list equivalent.